# $(document).ready starts after any flash obj. downloaded in IE?

Tags: jquery, flash

I've noticed something weird at IE.
When i have a flash object (.swf) inside a page, then any action/function inside $(document).ready starts after the swf object has been fully loaded. (While in firefox, it doesn't need the swf to be fully loaded)

Why is this happening, and how can i prevent it?

Comment: For what it's worth, on Firefox jQuery uses the clean `DOMContentLoaded` event to trigger `ready`, whereas on IE it uses the horrible hack described at http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/. Quite why `doScroll` only appears after the Flash is loaded is unclear, but then quite why the whole thing works at all is unclear...

Answer (score 3):

A simple <del>hack</del> solution is to not embed the swf until the page is loaded. Leave a blank `div` with a given id, and use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed the swf in the `div` on document ready.

Comment: Using swfobject will also guard you against future embedding incompatibility between different browsers, as the object/embed voodoo is enclosed in the library.